# Geometric interpretation of $0$-cycles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

I am learning about cycles on schemes, and I am wondering how I can think about a $0$-cycle, $1$-cycle (or more generally, $r$-cycle) geometrically?

Comment: This is pretty much the definition, but a $0$-cycle is basically a set of (closed) points, each with a multiplicity. Same thing with an $r$-cycle: it is a set of $r$-dimensional subvarieties, with multiplicity.